# How to add members to a distribution list using exchangelib

Tags: python, automation, exchangelib

How to add members to a distribution list in exchange2010 using python exchangelib? Any other library available to perform these tasks?

Comment: Also please help me to get list of DL's in exchange server 2010

Comment: Please help me to get it done.

Comment: Appreciate help on this.

Comment: You can only hope to do that with exchangelib if EWS supports it. Have you seen documentation that it's possible with EWS?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/cf855703-341d-4421-8afc-68c4975bd955/add-and-remove-users-from-exchange-distribution-groups-programmatically-c?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment    I dont think so, EWS has such options. Any alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: Then you should look into PowerShell commands that you can run directly on the Exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

"Also please help me to get list of DL's in exchange server 2010" => see below, code to get members of distribution list.

```
def get_distro_emails(dist_list):
    credentials = Credentials('username', os.environ.get('password'))
    account = Account('someone@company.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
    emails = []
    try:
        for mailbox in account.protocol.expand_dl(dist_list):
            emails.append(mailbox.email_address)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    return emails
```